# I need to know if my application is safe from XSS attacks

Tags: security, xss

I've a form with the input:

```
<html:text name="grupo" maxlength="15" property="name" size="20" alt="Nombre del grupo" />
```

And when submit the form, i call the JavaScript Function to validate the field:

```
function validate(theForm){
 var value = validate_null(theForm.name);
 return value;}

function validate_null(field){
if (field.value == ''){
  alert('Debe ingresar un valor en ' + field.alt);
  field.focus();
  return(false);
}
else return(true);}
```

Comment: This is a nice user experience feature but has nothing to do with xss. Client-side input validation is nothing more than UX, and server side input validation also has little to do with xss, which is an output encoding issue.

Comment: @GaborLengyel could you be more detailed? What is UX? My fear is that input evaluated in JavaScript function.